# How does one do web-scraping on JavaScript-driven websites?

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest

I've gotten my interest in the web-scraping after watching a few YouTube video recommendations regarding this specific subject.

The main thing I've learned and noticed is that the scraping is way much faster via a 'request(s)' library rather than a 'headless browser / library' and this made me ask myself a few questions. Of course I couldn't answer them nor was I able to find the required information on the internet, since my way of asking questions is quite different than what's expected.

In continuation, I'll use the terms 'script' or 'scripts', but what I do mean is the dynamic rendering of a page via 'AJAX', 'jQuery' or even 'JavaScript' calls.

As a summary after viewing the videos, in the past few months I was astonished by this website in China that has some of the greatest cooking recipes I've came across, but the problem is that the content is locked behind a login process. I want to scrape some of the recipes so I can take them to a translator because there seems to be a story behind every recipe and that's just amazing.

Anyway, I did use the 'Inspect' mode of the Chrome to see what's going on and I've seen that the login process is protected, because if I try to go to that specific part of the website (e.g.: '/api.php/api-ajax/login'), it says 'Access denied - You don't have permission to access <> on this server.'; and I think it's due to a WebDAV protocol or an intermediary server.

Because the login doesn't seem to have a 'Remember me' button, it disconnects me after about 1 hour even if I am or not active on the page and thus I may need to keep the scraping program fully aware of that.

My main concerns about web-scraping are:

- How to do web-scraping (if possible) without a headless browser (because the speed / performance is the main factor of web-scraping) on a website that's driven by scripts?
- How to create POST requests to a protected API / domain (if possible, using a non-headless browser method)?
- Is there a way to use proxy servers while scraping?
- How to wait for specific scripts to finish loading? I'm asking this because I've seen that the page is fully functional only after loading 2 or more scripts, the rest of the loading time being consumed by the loading of the images and CSS, which aren't very important - making the page to look like it's loading endlessly.

What I was referring in all of this is information gathered from the videos and from what I've noticed in the 'Inspect' option of the Chrome.

P.S. I'm sorry if you may find that this isn't the appropriate website to post such question, but I really don't know who or where else to ask.

Comment: As a side note, I'm open to any programming language that you may suggest.